# javascript registration issue

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fbform(){
    var isValid =true;
    var fullnameExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var noExp = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
    var fbname= document.getElementById('fbname'); 
    var fbnumber= document.getElementById('fbnumber');

    if(fbname.value.match(fullnameExp)){
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML="[Please type in alphabets only!]";
        isValid = false;
    }

    if(fbnumber.value.match(noExp)){
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errornumber").innerHTML="[Please type in 10 numbers only!]";
        isValid = false;
    } 
    alert("You are registereddddd");
    return isValid;
}

function reset_msgname() {
    document.getElementById('errorname').innerHTML = '';
}

function reset_msgnumber() {
    document.getElementById('errornumber').innerHTML = '';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myfb" method="post" onSubmit = "return fbform();">
<table width="736">
    <tr>
      <td width="114">Name:</td>
      <td width="335"> <input type='text' id='fbname' size="50" onClick= "reset_msgname()"/>
       <span id="errorname"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone number:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="fbnumber" size="50" onClick= "reset_msgnumber()"/>
      <span id="errornumber"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" ><input type= "Submit" value="Submit"/></input>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

hello guys, i have 1 issue here. now what im trying to fix is only when i click submit and the information is correct then i want to alert("you are registered") but now im not sure why it keep showing up even thought the information (to be filled) doesnt meet the criteria

Comment: Put a condition on `alert("You are registereddddd");`. The way you have it, it's set to fire every time `fbform()` executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no condition for showing up the alert. So, it will popup all the time. Just set the condition like this within `fbform()` function.

```
if(isValid){
     alert("You are registereddddd");
}
```